# JDBC loses ability to connect to MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**Situation**

I'm trying to build a simple JavaEE application. I'm running a MySQL-database in WSL and have TomEE configured in/via IntelliJ in windows. I have succesfully connected to the database in this setup before. After continuing developing my application and redeploying to test progress I suddenly started getting "Communications link failure" exceptions. Nothing changed in my pom.xml or code concerning connection. Netstat command in WSL-terminal shows MySQL is listening on expected port.

**Error message in IntelliJ console**

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
    ... 52 more
```

**Connection code**

```
public Connection getConnection() throws RuntimeException {

        try {
            DatabaseProperties props = new DatabaseProperties();

            var url = props.getUrl();
            var host = props.getHost();
            var password = props.getPassword();

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, host, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    }
```

**database.properties file**

```
url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spotitube
host = root
password = wachtwoord
```

**pom depedency**

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Output - netstat -tulnp**

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

**Output - sudo service mysql status**

```
 /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 23 min 33 sec
```

**Now what?**

I tried:

- restarting MySQL server
- restarting TomEE server
- mvn clean

Nothing helped. As I stated before, this code and setup worked before. Anybody any idea what I can try?